# Strange issue with webpack when importing vue, jquery & lodash

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, vue.js, lodash

So I was testing webpack with Vue and cannot seem to understand why the following is happening.

I have a main.js in which I am importing vue, jquery and lodash

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import $ from 'jquery'
import _ from 'lodash'
```

Then in the index.html file I'm adding the bundle.js

Now, the strange thing is that I can access _ (lodash library) directly from within the index.html file and but it refuses to recognize Vue or $

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do the following:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import $ from 'jquery';
import _ from 'lodash';

window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
```

Comment: I think it's better to use `webpack.ProvidePlugin` rather than global variables.

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/

Comment: @Sletheren Nope. So does that means the lodash library is doing that itself while the jquery library isn't ?

Comment: @GONG yes, you're right, however my concern here is that why is the lodash library accessible. It would make sense if none of the libraries were accessible.

Comment: @Storm its known issue of lodash itself https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1798